# Extend followup context lifespan?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Feel free to point out if I'm misguided in my intent (no pun intended), but I was trying to work on a conversation flow where the user is prompted with a yes/now question as a followup to a search like intent.

They say yes if the response matches what they were looking for, or no if it doesn't.  If no, I continue to follow up (for a while) with other options.

The followup intent is hit a couple of times before the context expires.  I was thinking it would make sense for me to bump the lifespan by 1 every time I offer a new suggestion.

Is this a good approach?  If so, is there a correct way to just basically do a context.lifespan++ or do i need to look up the existing context and overwrite it?

Thanks!

Imagine a flow like this.  The first input triggers the parent intent.
The Yes/No answers should hit the follow up intent.

```
> 'Suggest food'  
< 'Potato'   (followup lifespan 1)
> 'No'       
< 'Taco'     (followup lifespan undefined)
> 'No'       
< 'Pizza'    (followup context gone)
> 'No'
```

That last no does not trigger the follow up intent b/c the context has expired.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to extend the lifetime of your contexts. I've struggled with this for a number of hours too before I started using this:

```
Intent: question
Trainings phrase: 'May I enter?'
Output context: 'await_olderThan21'
Response: 'Are you older than 21?'

Intent: question.yes
Training phrase: 'yes'
Input context: 'await_olderThan21'
Output context: ''
Response: 'Yes, you may enter'

Intent: question.no
Training phrase: 'no'
Input context: 'await_olderThan21'
Output context: ''
Response: 'No, you may not.'

Intent: question.invalidInput
Training phrase: @sys.any
Input context: 'await_olderThan21'
Output context: 'await_olderThan21'
Response: 'Invalid answer. Please reply with yes or no.'
```

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Check out my edit, i think that explains my situation more clearly.  I was intending to hit the followup intent repeatedly (until i decide to stop providing more prompts)

Are you just setting the context again in the invalidInput intent?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you would want to use Dialogflow fulfillment. Basically you would save the sessionId of the user (so you can keep track of what you've asked the user). You would then programmatically set the output context based on if the content of [typesOfFoodArray] has been presented. 

If this makes sense ^ please let me know if it doesn't!

Comment: I have it doing this  but every time i say 'no' the lifespan of the followup context decreases by 1 until after 2 'no' followup responses, the context is gone.

I was thinking I needed to extend the lifespan by 1 everytime I hit the 'now' followup intent and offer a new suggestion.

Comment: Then I would give it a lifespan of 100 or so (something that won't be hit) and programmatically set the lifespan to 0 once your conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Yeah, that will definitely work.  Just didn't feel like the 'right' way.  I'm not against taking the path of less resistance some times, though.

Comment: That's what I would do. Some things just aren't possible without using fulfillment, just like the case you're describing.

Comment: Oh I am using webhook fulfillment. That is where i intended to programatically bump up the lifespan each time.  I didn't understand what you meant by dialogflow fulfillment.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting the context in the 'no' intent handling code.

conv.contexts.set('lookup-followup',1,undefined);